# History command execution with !bang after greping history not working correctly

Tags: bash

I have a problem with bash history.

Let's say I call the history with `history | grep forever`.
Then all former commands, that contain forever are displayed with their corresponding numbers.

If I now execute one of these commands with their corresponding number (e.g. `!2121`) a different command from the history is called and not the one that is associated with that number. What am I doing wrongly?

If I call the history without greping the bang-execution works as expected.

Thx

Scary example:

```
 ...
 1742  forever stop 0
 1743  forever -o out.log -e err.log start -c nodemon hotnews.js
 1784  forever list
 1814  forever list
 2496  forever -o out.log -e err.log start -c nodemon hotnews.js
 2498  forever -o out.log -e err.log start -c nodemon hotnews.js
 2957  forever -o out.log -e err.log start -c nodemon hotnews.js
 3292  forever -o out.log -e err.log start -c nodemon hotnews.js
 3452  forever -o out.log -e err.log start -c nodemon hotnews.js
 3603  forever -o out.log -e err.log start -c nodemon hotnews.js
 3614  history | grep forever
 [~]$ !1784
 npm uninstall express-flash
 npm WARN uninstall not installed in /home/development/node_modules: "express-flash"
 [~]$
```

Edit:

I remember that I changed my history properties in .bashrc:

```
# don't put duplicate lines or lines starting with space in the history.
# See bash(1) for more options
export HISTCONTROL=ignoreboth:erasedups

# append to the history file, don't overwrite it
shopt -s histappend

# for setting history length see HISTSIZE and HISTFILESIZE in bash(1)
export HISTSIZE=100000
export HISTFILESIZE=100000

# ignoriert einfache Befehle wie cd
export HISTIGNORE='cd:ls:bg:fg:history'

export PROMPT_COMMAND="history -a; history -c; history -r; $PROMPT_COMMAND"
```

Are these entries maybe somehow faulty?

Comment: Are you sure the number corresponds to the command in your `.bash_history` file?

Comment: Yeah, watch my example above.

Comment: Ok sorry. You were right Micheal9. The output of the history-command has different numbers than the .bash_history (cat -n .bash_history). How can this be?

Answer (score 0):

You probably have some blank lines or other stupid stuff in you .bash_history.
Try something like to find the bug:

```
history | tr -d '[:blank:]' > foo
cat -n .bash_history | tr -d '[:blank:] > bar
diff foo bar
```

Comment: The output of the history-command has different numbers than the .bash_history (cat -n .bash_history). How can this be? I thought the .bash_history file is the footing of the history command.

Comment: It should be identical, but when reading in hist ignores empty lines (and maybe other things). So take a look at there the numbers start to differ.